# Can I merge the buffers opened in one emacs process into the other emacs process?

Tags: terminal-emacs, process

In bash in a terminal emulator, I run two independent emacs processes. 
I created them in bash by `emacs -nw` and in each, I opened several buffers.

I switch between them by making one process into background via Ctrl-Z and then making the other into forground via `fg <jobid>`.

Since switching between them is inconvenient, is it possible to merge the buffers opened in one emacs process into the other emacs process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but you *can* use the client/server functionality in Emacs to simply connect to the *exact same* Emacs instance each time.  After starting the server you would use `emacsclient -nw` to connect to the server instance, instead of starting a completely separate instance with `emacs -nw`. You will have access to the same set of buffers in all clients.

See: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Emacs Server`

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean there is no way to merge the buffers in the two emacs processes created by `emacs -nw`?

Comment: Correct. At least to the very best of my knowledge -- I'm not an expert on the internals of Emacs, but I can't envisage any way that could work.

Comment: That said, if you're only talking about file-visiting buffers and you don't care about losing undo history, then you can simply re-visit the files of one instance in the other, and you could use the `desktop.el` library to do it for you. In one instance you could `M-x desktop-save` and in the other you could `M-x desktop-read`. If you're not saving to the default location, you may need to customize `desktop-path` for the instance in which you're going to read the desktop file.

Comment: n.b. I briefly but mistakenly suggested that `desktop-change-dir` could be used to select a directory to read from. Don't do that! It actually kills existing buffers and then reads the new desktop, which is not what you want.